# R Markdown Workflow to Render a Powerpoint Presentation as PDF

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc, file-conversion

I have begun using Rmd to render Powerpoint presentations consistently, using the YAML tags and more importantly, a reference Powerpoint to ensure standardized / consistent formatting:
`output: powerpoint_presentation: slide: reference_doc: "reference.pptx"`. When I want to share a PPT document as a reference for my peers / students however, I want to be able to have my slides available as a .pdf file.

I have had success using shell commands in R using LibreOffice's soffice command, however I am not always at a workstation with that available. Is there a portable solution / executable I can call, or additional Rmd tags  for rendering a document with a .pptx reference document, but rendered as a .pdf file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have to specifiy `output: beamer_presentation` in the header.
Take a look at this: https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/formats.html